# Como criar uma TRIGGER para um evento INSERT sem causar um lock na tabela do SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Olá, estou fazendo a integração entre 2 soluções, onde preciso detectar a alteração de uma tabela, e, baseado nas informações que forem enviadas eu devo manipular outra tabela. Não tenho acesso a 1ª solução para fazer com que ela mesma faça essa alteração, com base nessa premissa eu tive que criar uma `TRIGGER`.

Meu problema é que, quando a `TRIGGER` é executada, ela **faz um lock na tabela da 1º solução o que está impedindo de colocar a 2º solução em um ambiente de produção...** Existe alguma forma de criar uma `TRIGGER` que não cause um lock, ou então algum outro recurso que me permita capturar as informações na inserção no banco e usá-las sem impedir a 1ª solução de trabalhar?

Comment: Se você fizer a `query` que busca as informações com `WITH (NOLOCK)` no `SELECT` provavelmente você não terá mais esse problema

Comment: Então a query que estiver dentro da trigger? Porque eu uso algumas das informações da atualização da trigger para alimentar outra tabela

Comment: Melhor você colocar o código da `TRIGGER` para podermos opinar, senão fica muito genérica a pergunta e não tem como te dar uma solução definitiva

Comment: "eu devo manipular outra tabela." , o que seria isto ? Se este tratamento for pesado pode mesmo onerar a operação toda. Pela descrição de não ter acesso a solução indica um pacote ou sistema fornecido , é isto ? Falou com o resposável pelo mesmo ? Sem a estrutura vai ficar difícil opinar.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção seria usar o comando NOLOCK. Ele avisa o processador do SQL Server para evitar a utilização de bloqueios (LOCK) durante a leitura de dados. Porém, o SQL Server continua utilizando os bloqueios durante operações de modificação de dados e não há como mudar esse comportamento. A utilização do NOLOCK é, portanto, inválida para as tabelas que terão registros afetados por INSERT, DELETE e UPDATE.

```
INSERT tbUsuarios WITH (NOLOCK) (nome) VALUES ('A')

DELETE tbUsuarios WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE id = 1

UPDATE tbUsuarios WITH (NOLOCK) SET nome = 'B' WHERE id = 1
```

Esses comandos resultam no erro:

> Msg 1065, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>
> The NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITTED lock hints are not allowed for target
>   tables of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statements.

Entretanto a restrição do NOLOCK se aplica somente à tabela que receberá os novos registros, sendo ainda possível utilizar NOLOCK para as tabelas que fornecem os registros. Exemplo:

```
INSERT tbHistorico (Nome)
SELECT Nome FROM tbUsuarios WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Fonte: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fcatae/2010/10/11/update-with-nolock-como-funciona/